# Style.width and left doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the effect of a "photo strip" in a menu div with this background

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Y_uUwNwvSU8/SJUSQzlYMXI/AAAAAAAAAA8/5IYVcaRaJDA/S660/tira%2Bfotografica.jpg

Im changing the width and left of the div to simulate this effect with javascript/jquery but it doesn't work this way, for now is "onclick" but i want to make it automatically may be with **setInterval**?

**Here's the HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "PruebaIndex.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var slider = document.getElementById("#slider");
            var speed = 10;
            $("#slider").click(function(){
                slider.style.width = (slider.style.width+speed)+"px";
                slider.style.left = (slider.style.left-speed)+"px";
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <div id = "slider">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here's the CSS Code:**

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#slider {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("TiraFotografica.PNG");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 800px;
    height: 304px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I tried anothers different ways, like **window.onload**, putting the code after all in **body**, trying $(object).width, etc.. the problem is that when i click this doesn't move, then later i'll try to do automatically..

**I have another doubt, this menu will get divs inside (options), when i make this div ("#slider") move, those divs moves too (the options)?**

**EDIT: I added this by DinoMyte**

```
var speed = 10;
$("#slider").click(function(){
    $(this).css("width",(parseInt($(this).css("width").replace("px","")) + speed) + "px");
    $(this).css("left",(parseInt($(this).css("left").replace("px","")) - speed) + "px");
});
```

**Now it works fine, just need to make this automatically without clicks**

**sorry for my bad english..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `slider.style.width` would give you the width + "px" , so `(slider.style.width+speed)` isn't going to work. You need to replace "px" first. Also you need to parse the current width value to an integer.

```
slider.style.width = parseInt(slider.style.width.replace("px","")) +speed)+"px";
```

The better way to do this :

```
  var speed = 10;
    $("#slider").click(function(){
        $(this).css("width",(parseInt($(this).css("width").replace("px","")) + speed) + "px");
        $(this).css("left",(parseInt($(this).css("left").replace("px","")) - speed) + "px");
    });
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/a2n234eq/6/

Comment: I got a solution similar, and ur code work, but the "left" doesn't get lower i dont know why, i tried with $(this).left() and nothing..

Comment: the left seems to be working fine. I took out additional stuff. try this : https://fiddle.jshell.net/a2n234eq/8/

Comment: I put the alert that u did, and it prints "NaN", it should not print a number? i print the width in alert and it says "800", "810" its fine, but i dont know why left prints "NaN".

Comment: I tried to print the left margin without parse and it prints "auto" but i defined the margin to 0 and still prints "auto".

Comment: Check this : https://fiddle.jshell.net/a2n234eq/9/. Also, in the css, i have defined left as 50px, so on every subsequent clicks, you should get value - 10